# SERVICES in sending ENTITIES in distributed systems

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, distributed-system

Here is a passage from the Blue book:

```
Distributed system architectures, such as J2EE and CORBA, provide
special publishing mechanisms for SERVICES , with conventions for
their use, and they add distribution and access capabilities. But such
frameworks are not always in use on a project, and even when they
are, they are likely to be overkill when the motivation is just a logical
separation of concerns.
```

Does this mean that DOMAIN SERVICES should handle serialization of ENTITIES and send them to another `SERVICE` on an another machine in the cluster? Should SERVICE on the another machine also handle receiving and de-serialization of the request omitting the presentation layer?

**So the questions is:**

Should  DOMAIN SERVICES make requests to other DOMAIN SERVICES on different machine if they are within the same bounded context?

Comment: What makes you think so? Assuming the services mentioned there are domain services, in a vacuum, the excerpt seems to say something different or even opposite to what you wrote. But it would clarify the question if you included your thought process about it.

Comment: @guillaume31 well the question remains: should  DOMAIN SERVICES make requests to other DOMAIN SERVICES on different machine if they are within the same bounded context

Comment: The question makes little technical sense, as domain services are not located in a layer that allows them to reach out to or be contacted by the outside world. Which makes me think there is a misunderstanding about the excerpt or even the whole chapter.

Comment: Most people find the blue book hard to read, and this passage illustrates why. Maybe a better question would be if someone can explain what Evans actually means here…

Comment: @RikD it’s also a relatively short passage and out of context, which doesn’t help :)

Comment: @guillaume31 I re-read part of the chapter yesterday and even though I almost never use domain services myself, it’s quite clear when they could be considered. But the part about *”Access to services”* is suddenly dropped out of nowhere. What is your opinion of it? What are we supposed to learn from that part?

Comment: @RikD I re-read the passage and summed it up in an answer - in short, he's not talking about domain services specifically.

Answer (score 1):

In that passage, Evans is not strictly talking about domain services but service as a feature, a unit of behavior exposed to callers.

On the previous page, there is a chart of the different types of services in each layer and their interactions. It is clearly stated that an Application service can call a Domain service and an Infrastructure service. All this together forms a service feature.

The highlighted extract simply means that you don't always need to distribute your service behavior. It can simply stay in-process when you only need logical separation of concerns. What's important is the way you design your service and the responsibilities you give it, not so much how it is exposed.

The next paragraph goes on to explain what other, non-distributed ways of exposing a service can look like - a "doer" object, a Singleton - and sums it up with:

> Elaborate architectures should be used only when there is a real need to distribute the system or otherwise draw on the framework's capabilities.